# Inner Join & PHP

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

So this is my first time properly approaching INNER JOIN Statements and I have been trying my hand at it, needless to say it isnt going well. Below is my page code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/reps.php'); ?>
<?php

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$query_orders = "SELECT * FROM orders";
$orders = mysql_query($query_orders, $reps) or die(mysql_error());
$row_orders = mysql_fetch_assoc($orders);
$totalRows_orders = mysql_num_rows($orders);

mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$query_staff = "SELECT * FROM staff";
$staff = mysql_query($query_staff, $reps) or die(mysql_error());
$row_staff = mysql_fetch_assoc($staff);
$totalRows_staff = mysql_num_rows($staff);

mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$query_products = "SELECT * FROM products";
$products = mysql_query($query_products, $reps) or die(mysql_error());
$row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products);
$totalRows_products = mysql_num_rows($products);

mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$join = "SELECT
orders.ID AS id,
orders.CustomerName AS customerName,
orders.StaffMember AS staffMember,
orders.SalesPrice AS salesPrice,
orders.ListPrice AS listPrice,
orders.AgeOfPayment AS productAge,
orders.Product AS productName,
orders.Quantity AS orderQuantity,
orders.DateOfOrder AS orderDate,
staff.Bonus AS staffBonus,
products.Price AS productPrice
FROM
orders AS orders
INNER JOIN staff AS staff ON orders.StaffMember = staff.StaffName
INNER JOIN products AS products ON orders.Product = products.ProductName
ORDER BY
orderDate ASC";

$joinresult = mysql_query($join);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<?php


require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("models/header.php");

?>
</head>

<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='top'>
  <div id='logo'></div>
</div>
<div id='content'>
  <h1></h1>
  <h2>Change This</h2>
  <div id='left-nav'>
    <?php include("left-nav.php"); ?>
  </div>
  <div id='main'>
    <div id ="orderstable">
      <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
          <th>Order ID</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Sales Price (€)</th>
          <th>Total Sale (€)</th>
          <th>List Price (€)</th>
          <th>Price Difference (€)</th>
          <th>% Difference</th>
          <th>Sold By</th>
          <th>Order Date</th>
          <th>Age of Payment</th>
          <th>Bonus %</th>
          <th>Bonus Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <?php do { ?>
        <?php do { ?>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['ID']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_join['customerName']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_join['product']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['Quantity']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['SalesPrice']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php $first_multiply = $row_orders['Quantity'];
                                               $second_multiply = $row_orders['SalesPrice'];
                                               $multiply_total = $first_multiply *  $second_multiply;
                                               echo ($multiply_total); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['Price']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php $first_number = $row_orders['Price']; 
                                                $second_number = $row_orders['SalesPrice'];
                                                $sum_total = $first_number - $second_number;
                                                echo ($sum_total); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">as</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_join['staffMember']; ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', $row_orders['orderDate']); ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row_orders['bonus']; ?>%</td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <?php } while ($row_orders = mysql_fetch_assoc($orders));?>
          <?php } while ($row_join = mysql_fetch_array($join));?>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='bottom'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html><?php
mysql_free_result($orders);

mysql_free_result($staff);

mysql_free_result($products);
?>
```

What I am basically trying to do is the following:

- An order is submitted from a page before this. The data is stored on the table in the database and echoed out.
- The three tables in question are the staff, orders and products tables
- I saved the form based on the ID and not the value. I have googled and researched INNER JOIN and I tried the below which didn't work.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
o.ID,
o.CustomerName,
o.StaffMember,
o.SalesPrice,
o.ListPrice,
o.AgeOfPayment,
o.Product,
o.Quantity,
o.DateOfOrder,
s.Bonus,
p.Price
FROM
`orders` o
INNER JOIN staff AS s ON o.StaffMember = s.StaffName
INNER JOIN products AS p ON o.Product = p.ProductName
WHERE o.StaffMember = s.StaffName 
AND o.Product = p.ProductName
ORDER BY
orderDate ASC";
```

However, I have a feeling that your tables are not constructed well. I would suggest using IDs instead of Product = ProductName etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the join like this:

```
$join = "SELECT  o.ID id,
                 o.CustomerName customerName,
                 o.StaffMember staffMember,
                 o.SalesPrice salesPrice,
                 o.ListPrice listPrice,
                 o.AgeOfPayment productAge,
                 o.Product productName,
                 o.Quantity orderQuantity,
                 o.DateOfOrder orderDate,
                 s.Bonus staffBonus,
                 p.Price productPrice
         FROM    
                 orders o,
                 staff s,
                 products p
         WHERE
                 o.StaffMember = s.StaffName
         AND
                 o.Product = p.ProductName
         ORDER BY
                 orderDate";
```

since you have 2 conditions when joining 3 tables, you will get all results.  You can put in another `AND` where you present something unique to the `orders` table and get this information about a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that mysql_ functions are deprecated in PHP now. You may want to switch to mysqli_ (is very comparable to the mysql_ class) or PDO.